# slack, php and json - Valid Markup for iterating app selections

Tags: php, mysql, json, slack

I've been trying to create a slack app which takes the basic information of the name and sku of the product and places it within a select box that appears in slack. Unfortunately my code to populate the valid json is going wrong somewhere when i try to itterate using a loop.

**Valid Json is here:**

```
{
    "text": "Great! You want to find something!",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "text": "Please type what you want to find",
            "fallback": "Sorry! Cant do that at the moment!",
            "callback_id": "cg_selectproduct",
            "color": "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",

            "actions": [

                {
                    "name": "cg_choice",
                    "text": "Find Product",
                    "type": "select",
                    "options": [
                        {
                                "text": "option1",
                                "value": "option1"
                        },

                        {
                                "text": "option2",
                                "value": "option2"
                        },
                        {
                                "text": "option3",
                                "value": "option3"
                        }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This works perfectly fine without the iteration. I have no issues if i tell the app to go here. It displays all options correctly.

**Invalid PHP**

```
$check = ($dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE FAMILY='PARENT'"));
$check->execute();
$row = $check->fetchAll();
// execute a pdo search to find all product parents

$jsonInput = "";
foreach($row as $rows){
$jsonInput .= '"text"=>"' . $rows['PRODUCT_NAME'] . '", "value" => "' . $rows['SKU'] . '",';
}
$jsonInput = rtrim($jsonInput, ',');
//Create an iterative string which will contain the product names and skus, removing the comma at the end.

header('Content-Type: application/json');
//Set the content type to json


$optionSelect = array(
    "text" => "Great! You want to find something!",
    "attachments" =>array(
            "text" => "Please type what you want to find",
            "fallback" => "Sorry! Cant do that at the moment!",
            "callback_id" => "cg_selectproduct",
            "color"=> "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type" => "default",

            "actions" => array(
                    "name" => "cg_choice",
                    "text" => "Find Product",
                    "type" => "select",
                    "options" => array($jsonInput)
                        )

           )

    );
//Create and itterate the options for the selection so it's populated

print_r(json_encode($optionSelect));
//print to show json
```

I'm not 100% sure where i'm going wrong with this. Maybe i'm thinking about a minor part a little too much. Can anyone here help me with where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jsonInput = [];
foreach($row as $rows) {
    $jsonInput[] = array(
        'text' => $rows['PRODUCT_NAME'],
        'value' => $rows['SKU']
    );
}

// ...........

"options" => $jsonInput
```

Comment: You sir, are a hero.

Comment: Although this does work as i'm looking for, i've still hit a bit of a snag. It seems the generated output doesn't match the json output. See here: [link](http://puu.sh/x6x9v.png) The one on the left is the generated one and the one on the right is the valid json markup.

Comment: Then add zero-based indexes where needed. Example: "attachments" => array(array( ... - doble the array() key

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you very much.